# Error in libgraph installation :- missing libgraph.so.1 file in fedora 27

Tags: graphics, fedora

./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libgraph.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
ldd a.out :-inux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5bff4000) libgraph.so.1 => not found libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa242377000) libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa242022000) libgccs.so.1 => /lib64/libgccs.so.1 (0x00007fa241e0b000) libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa241a28000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2426fe000).
here i can see that libgraph.so.1 is missing what shall i do further to get that missing file.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem even with the correct libraries installed.
Try this:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
```

and compile and run again.